# If $L_1$ is regular and $L_1 \cap L_2$ context-free, is $L_2$ always context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

If $L_1$ is a regular language and $L_1 \cap L_2$ is a context-free language, does it mean that $L_2$ is a context-free language too?

I attempted to prove that $L_2$ was not required to be context-free by the following: If $L_1 = \{ a^n \}$ and $L_2 = \{ a^nb^nc^n \} $ then $L_1 \cap L_2 = \{ a^n \}$ which is context-free.

Is this a counterexample to show that $L_2$ is not required to be context-free? If not, then do you have any suggestions?

Comment: With your choices, $L_1 \cap L_2 = \{\varepsilon\}$.

Comment: with a tiny bit of editing you have your answer.

Comment: OP having solved his own problem (albeit with a small mistake), I think the question can be closed.